# How to make a partial update while using constructor instantiation with mapstruct and immutable kotlin objects

Tags: kotlin, dto, mapstruct

How to make a partial update while using constructor instantiation? Let's say I have a User entity and UserDto object and want to update just "name" and not "login" and "passHash". I don't want to make them mutable so I cannot use @MappingTarget.

Ideally I would like to set " nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE", pass a source object A: User, an existing (not updated) object B:UserDto and mapper would returned an object C:UserDto which would be the B object updated with non-null properties from A.

Something like this (kotlin):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface UserMapper {
    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun createEntityFromDto(dto: UserDto, @MappingExample entity: User) : User
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way MapStruct does partial updates is by using `@MappingTarget`, which means that the object you are trying to update has to be mutable. There is no other way to perform an update.

What you can do is to use some kind of builders and use the bulder in the `@MappingTarget` to perform the update.

e.g. in Java

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    void updateUser(@MappingTarget User.Builder userBuilder, UserDto userDto);
}
```

And then you can invoke it in the following way

```
User.Builder userBuilder = entity.toBulder();
userMapper.updateUser(userBuilder, userDto);
```